# Listing Kentico contact fields

Tags: kentico

I'm looking to develop a module for mapping data from an external database to Kentico on-line marketing contacts. Is there an easy way to list the field names and captions for all standard and custom fields from the built-in OM.Contact class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Getting data from external DB

There are tons of ways to get data from a database and put it in memory.  Here's one general-purpose script that I use a quite a bit:

```
    //Set the connection string
    string ConnectionString = externalDBConnectionString;

    //Sets the text of the query we want to execute on the database to a variable called queryText
    string queryText = "SELECT * FROM Table";

    //Creates a new instance of the SqlDataAdapter object and calls it "adapter".  
    //We pass in the text of the query we want to execute on the database, and the connetion string to the database.
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryText, ConnectionString);

    //Instantiate a dataset.
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    //Fills the dataset with the data retrieved by our query on the database.
    adapter.Fill(ds);
```

---

## Getting Data from Kentico

Getting data from Kentico is even easier.  Kentico has an API that uses Info objects, which are just simple data structures, and InfoProvider objects, which contain (among other things) methods for populating Info objects with data and executing CRUD operations on the Kentico DB.

They work like this:

```
    // Instantiate a ContactInfo object
    ContactInfo ci = new ContactInfo();

    // Populate it with data using the InfoProvider's GetContactInfo() method
    ci = new ContactInfoProvider.GetContactInfo(ContactID);

    // Shorthand
    ContactInfo ci = new ContactInfoProvider.GetContactInfo(ContactID);

    // Assign values to your server control properties using the properties of the Info object
    txtFormField.Text = ci.ContactName;
```

---

Moving data back and forth from your external DB and the Kentico DB would require you to map the fields and their respective data types to each other, then executing a query on DB with the formatted data.

Comment: I actually need to populate the list of contact fields in code and store then in a collection for processing. I want to be able to dynamically determine the list of contact fields.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood you.  You'll probably want to use the ContactInfo and ContactInfoProvider objects. I'll update my answer this evening to show you how to run CRUD operations on the Kentico database with InfoProvider objects.  All you do is populate a dataset with data from your external DB, insert it into an InfoObject, then Create/Update with an InfoProdiver object.  In the mean time, you can check out this guide from Kentico (start on page 184).  It's version 6, but the classes probably haven't changed much: http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/6_0/KenticoCMS_OnlineMarketingGuide.pdf

Comment: Oh, and you can use the data that you pass into the ContactInfo object to populate your form fields as well. Whether you're populating the Info object with data from your external DB or Kentico doesn't matter.

Comment: @emroc if this was the correct answer to your question, then you will want to click the check mark at the top of this answer.  It'll help future users and I'll get points ;)